# prototype.add がどんな動作をしているのか分からない。

Tags: javascript, typescript

TypeScriptを入門しようと思いTypeScript Deep Diveの日本語訳を読んでいるのですが、そこで説明されているJavaScriptのコードが理解出来ないです。

`Point.prototype.add`の箇所からいまいち分からないです。 `prototype.add`とは何でしょうか？

引数はおそらく上記で定義したPointをインスタンス化した物を取ると思うのですが `this.x`はどこから来るのか分かりません。

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
let test = new Point(10, 7);
// 実行結果は10になる。
console.log(test.x);


Point.prototype.add = function (point) {
    return new Point(this.x + point.x, this.y + point.y);
};
```

#### 追記

予想では10が表示されると思ったのですが、うまく動作しないです。

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
let point = new Point(10, 7);
Point.prototype.add = function (point) {
    return new Point(this.x + point.x, this.y + point.y);
};
console.log(Point.prototype.add.x)

//実行結果
undefined
undefined
```

#### 追記（上手くaddを使用出来た。）

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
Point.prototype.add = function (point) {
    return new Point(this.x + point.x, this.y + point.y);
};
let point = new Point(10, 7);
console.log(point.add(point))
console.log(point.x)
//実行結果
Point {x: 20, y: 14}
10
```

#### 追記（prototypeの意味を少し理解した。）

この `Point.prototype.add =` とする事でPointオブジェクトに後から `add()`メソッドを追加している事を意味していて、生成されたインスタンス間で同じ所（プロトタイプ）を参照している事が分かった。TypeScript deep diveではTypeScriptのclassはJavaScriptのES5では `prototype` を使用して実装されているという事を伝えたかったんだと思う。

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
const point1 = new Point(10, 7);
const point2 = new Point(4, 3);
//console.log(point1.__proto__.add)// ないとでる。
//console.log(point2.__proto__.add)// ないとでる。



Point.prototype.add = function (point) {
    return new Point(this.x + point.x, this.y + point.y);
};

console.log(point1.__proto__.add);
console.log(point2.__proto__.add);
```

#### 参照

https://typescript-jp.gitbook.io/deep-dive/future-javascript/classes/classes-emit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScriptはもともと**プロトタイプベース**のオブジェクト指向言語です
(現在は classキーワードも使用可能 … 使ったことはないけど, 微妙に異なるらしい)
それに対し Javaなどの言語は, **クラスベース**のオブジェクト指向言語です

参考(Wikipedia):

- [プロトタイプベース](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%88%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%97%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9)
- [クラスベース](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9)

プロトタイプチェーンを利用するには以下のように行います

```js
// 利用するときは new 演算子を使う
// プロパティーを持つ
function Graph() {
  this.vertexes = [];
  this.edges = [];
}

// メソッドを定義する (後から追加することも可能)
// (辞書形式で)複数指定可能
Graph.prototype = {
  addVertex: function(v){
    this.vertexes.push(v);
  }
};

var g = new Graph();
```

`g.addVertex(val)` などと呼び出すことができ, 自身のプロパティー `vertexes` に `val`を `push`します
解説は長くなるので, 以下のページを参照してください

参考 (MDN Web Docs)

- [継承とプロトタイプチェーン](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)
- [Object のプロトタイプ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)

---

(追記)

質問の `Point.prototype.add` とは, `Point.prototype`によって, `add`というメソッドを登録している, ということ
`this.x` や `this.y` とは, `Point`の持つプロパティーです

---

(追記_2)

メソッド `add`の使い方は以下のように

```js
let point = new Point(10, 7)

let addp = new Point(2, 1)
let newp = point.add(addp)   // あるいは直接 point.add(new Point(〜)) でも

console.log(newp)
// Object { x: 12, y: 8 }
console.log(point.add(new Point(-1,-1)))
// Object { x: 9, y: 6 }

// add は新しい Pointインスタンスを生成してるだけだから元の値は変わらない
console.log(point.x)
// 10
```

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます。
つまり上記の場合 `Point(10 + 10, 7 + 7)`みたいになるという事でしょうか？
`Point.prototype.add`って普通に `Point.prototype.add`で実行されるんでしょうか？その場合は先に `const point = new Point(10, 7)` インスタンスを作成してから実行するのでしょうか？すいません質問ばかりになってしまって。

Comment: 先にインスタンス作成してからですね。もちろん同時に `add`呼び出してもOK。`new Point(10,20).add(new Point(2,2))` とか

Comment: 思い通りに動作しました。ありがとうございます。